# Can we use Shimano XTR 2x11 speed shifter with Shimano 2x11 Dura-Ace RD and FD?

Tags: compatibility

Is Shimano XTR 2x11 shifter compatible with 2x11 Dura-ace RD and FD? I'm looking to upgrade my old bike with porteur type handlebar with some high-end components. I'm planning to make it like an all around sleeper bike but built with speed and being lightweight in mind.

Edit: Mechanical only

Comment: Is it Di2?  If not, it's not compatible.

Comment: mechanical only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shimano 11 speed MTB and road derailleurs and shifters are not compatible. The cable pull per shift and derailleur actuation ratios are different. See this Art's Cyclery page](https://www.artscyclery.com/science-behind-the-magic/science-behind-the-magic-drivetrain-compatibility/).

The MTB groups use a longer cable pull to be more reliable in dirty conditions.

While rear derailleur cable pull/actuation ratios are well documented, front ones are not, but I have to assume 11 speed MTB and road groups use different pulls and are not compatible.

MTB double cranks typically have a 10 tooth difference between rings whereas roads cranks have a 16 tooth difference. Cages on MTB front derailleurs are therefore smaller and will not work with road cranks.

Comment: But will it be compatible with a Dura-Ace FD? I have an old 52-36T 11 speed shimano crank here and I would like to use it on my bike. Would that be possible or should I use an MTB FD instead? I have checked on some MTB FD and they look so small. Would that make any incompatibility with my crank of choice?

Comment: @WashichawbachaW See update to answer

Comment: So MTB FD is not compatible with Road cranks 52-36T. Can I use Road FD instead?

Comment: @WashichawbachaW as I said in third paragraph, I assume front derailleur cable pull/actuation ratios used in MTB and road groups are different, the same as they are for rear derailleurs

Comment: So it's like really impossible to have an 11 speed 52-36T crank with MTB shifter given 11 speed FDs are incompatible with each other. Is there any other MTB shifter and road/MTB FD that is compatible with my crank?

Comment: @WashichawbachaW Road drivetrains with flat bar shifters isn't a well served area (at least by Shimano), Tiagra, Sora and Claris all have flat bar shifters as well as drop bar shifters, but those are 10 and 9 speed groups. SRAM has better options I believe as some of their MTB and road groups share actuation ratios.

Comment: You can look into J-tek Shiftmate to see if it's possible to use the shifter/derailluer combo you want. Another solution would be to use bar-end shifters with something like Paul's Thumbies. https://www.paulcomp.com/product-category/components/drivetrain/shifting/

Comment: If you can find 9 speed front XT shifter and an 9 speed front derailluer those are compatible and will likely work well enough with an 11 speed crank. A more common problem is shifting 11spd MTB with road shifters and there are solutions for that ( J-Tek shiftmate or wolftooth TanPan).

Comment: Also microshift seems to be filling in a lot of the gaps that the Big component makers. 11 spd flat bar, etc..

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention whether you are asking about mechanical or electronic (Di2).  Assuming you have mechanical components, the answer is "no".

The shifter cable pull between MTB and Road Shimano components is not compatible.

Comment: Lopez mechanical only.